# swift UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, exif

I need to get location data (coordinates for latitude and longitude) from an image picked from PhotoLibrary using UIImagePickerController. [Existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos/33672661#33672661) proposes using fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs, but it is deprecated for iOS 8 to 11, so I wonder what's the alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. For new iOS versions, use the following lines of code.

```
var asset: PHAsset?
asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset
```

Note that `asset = nil` if the user did not give permission to access his Photo Library since the PHAsset data is sensitive.

To obtain permission, edit `Info.plist` accordingly and request for permission using `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization()`.

Comment: This is outdated Swift code. You had trouble with my answer since you seem to be using an older version of Swift and Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only supporting iOS 11 and later then you can directly get the `PHAsset` using the `.phAsset` key. You only need to use `PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs` if you need to support iOS 10 or earlier.

Once you have the `PHAsset` reference, then you can access the `location` property to get the coordinates of the image.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    var asset: PHAsset?
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        asset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset
    } else {
        if let url = info[.referenceURL] as? URL {
            let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
            asset = result.firstObject
        }
    }

    if let asset = asset {
        if let location = asset.location {
            print("Image location is \(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get it simply by `image.ciImage.properties` ?

Comment: @TheTiger `CIImage properties` doesn't appear to have anything to do with image metadata. It appears to be about filter metadata.

Comment: Have you checked `image.ciImage.properties[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String]` ? I'm not sure but this is the way I add the location to image in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222591/1140335).

Comment: @TheTiger I really don't know anything `CIImage properties`. `image.ciImage` is likely to be `nil` when selecting an image from the photo library so even if you can get the location from the `CIImage properties`, it may not work in this case anyway. Either way, the focus of the question and this answer is about accessing through the PHAsset. If you can confirm that `CIImage` works in this situation, post an answer.

Comment: hi thanks! I added the code accordingly and I get this error for the line " asset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset " : " Slice<Dictionary<String, Any>>' is not convertible to 'PHAsset' ". may i know what's wrong. sorry if it's a rookie mistake, still new to this.

Comment: The code in my answer is written in Swift 4.2/Xcode 10.